# Pushing(sending) a single variable to new Class with multiple arguments

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to push kombiController.text value to a new class, but after trying all sorts of things, I just don't know what else to do. I'm getting an error "8 positional arguments expected, but found 0, which I'm guessing is due to my FeedbackForm class requiring 8, but I don't find solution to how to fix it or set up some default paramaters.

Note: The other variable message-ekipaController is getting sent normally and I had no troubles implementing it.

I've been trying to fix and find a solution to this "little" problem for 2 days now and no matter from which angle I try to resolve this issue, I just get new problems somewhere else.

mainscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'secondscreen.dart';
import 'models/feedback_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  String kombi;
  String valuePolja;

  TextEditingController ekipaController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController kombiController = new TextEditingController();

  // Default Drop Down Item.
  String dropdownValue = 'Tom Cruise';

  // To show Selected Item in Text.
  String holder = '' ;

  List listItem = [
    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
  ];

  void getDropDownItem(){

    setState(() {
      holder = dropdownValue ;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DHL"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              TextFormField(
                controller: ekipaController,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  valuePolja = text;
                },
                validator: (value){
                  if(value.isEmpty){
                    return "Enter Valid Name";
                  }else{
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Ime Ekipe",
                ),
              ),

              DropdownButton(
                hint: Text("Izberi Kombi: "),
                dropdownColor: Colors.white,
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                value: kombi,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    kombi = newValue;
                  });
                  kombiController.text = newValue;
                },
                items: listItem.map((valueItem) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: valueItem,
                    child: Text(valueItem),
                  );
                }).toList(),

              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
                  child :
                  //Printing Item on Text Widget
                  Text('Selected Item = ' + kombiController.text,
                      style: TextStyle (fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black))),

              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Next Screen',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(message: ekipaController.text)));
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FeedbackForm(kombiController: kombiController.text)));
                }
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

feedback_form.dart

```
import 'package:dhl_app/mainscreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class FeedbackForm extends StatefulWidget  {

  const FeedbackForm(this.ime_ekipe, this.ime_stranke, this.postna_stevilka, this.teza, this.type, this.datum, this.dostavljeno, this.kombiController);

  final String kombiController;
  final String ime_ekipe;
  final String ime_stranke;
  final String postna_stevilka;
  final String teza;
  final String type;
  final String datum;
  final String dostavljeno;

  //FeedbackForm(this._ime_ekipe, this._ime_stranke, this._postna_stevilka, this._teza, this._type, this._datum, this._dostavljeno, this.kombiController);

  String toParams() => "?ime_ekipe=$ime_ekipe&ime_stranke=$ime_stranke&postna_stevilka=$postna_stevilka&teza=$teza&type=$type&datum=$datum&dostavljeno=$dostavljeno&kombi=$kombiController";

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
```

secondscreen.dart (where the other variable works)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'models/controller.dart';
import 'models/feedback_form.dart';
import 'mainscreen.dart';


class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final String message;

  const SecondScreen({Key key, this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  _SecondScreen createState() => _SecondScreen();
}

class _SecondScreen extends State<SecondScreen> {


  var _controller = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  //TextField Controllers
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController feedbackController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController typeController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dostavljenoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController kombiController = TextEditingController();

  void _submitForm(){

    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      FeedbackForm feedbackForm = FeedbackForm(
        nameController.text,
        emailController.text,
        phoneNumberController.text,
        feedbackController.text,
        typeController.text,
        dateController.text,
        dostavljenoController.text,
        kombiController.text,
      );

      FormController formController = FormController(
              (String response) {
            print(response);
            if(response == FormController.STATUS_SUCCESS){
              _showSnackBar("Feedback Submitted!");
            }else {
              _showSnackBar("Error Occured!");
            }
          });

      _showSnackBar("Submitting Feedback");
      formController.submitForm(feedbackForm);
    }
  }

  _showSnackBar(String message) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(message),);
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Vnesi Podatke"),
      ),
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50, horizontal: 24),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget> [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Name";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "${widget.message}",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => nameController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: emailController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Email";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Ime Stranke",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => emailController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: phoneNumberController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Mobile Number";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Poštna Številka",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => phoneNumberController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: feedbackController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Feedback";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Kilogramov",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => feedbackController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: typeController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Feedback";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Tip",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => typeController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: dateController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Feedback";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Datum",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => dateController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: dostavljenoController,
                    validator: (value){
                      if(value.isEmpty){
                        return "Enter Valid Feedback";
                      }else{
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Dostavljeno",
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => dostavljenoController.clear(),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: _submitForm,
                    child: Text('Submit Feedback'),
                  )
                ],
              )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your FeedbackForm has a constructor with 8 parameters but inside the mainscreen.dart you pass only the kombiController value when creating the FeedbackForm instance.

Comment: I know what you are saying and I'm aware of that, but I don't know how do I set up this FeedbackForm instance with default paramaters. I'm missing some fundamental knowledge and just want to know how to set it up, because I have an idea of what is going on, but have no idea of how to set up the instance inside mainscreen.dart when I'm pushing it.

Comment: So if you know that the problem is the constructor, just surf the Dart documentation and check on how to define default parameters. You can use named parameters and define the default values like this: `const FeedbackForm({this.ime_ekipe = '...', this. ime_stranke = '...',...})`

Comment: The thing is we don't get these paramaters from mainscreen.dart (except for kombiController.text), but from secondscreen.dart, so I can't run this from mainscreeen, unless I give default values into FeedbackForm instane in mainscreen and then override them after we submit data from secondscreen.

I tried this MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FeedbackForm({this.ime_ekipe = "...", this.ime_stranke = "...", this.postna_stevilka="...", this.teza=.. but still get the error.

Comment: If that's the case, you should keep all the controllers in the `MainScreen` and pass them to the SecondsScreen when you need to fill in the data. This way, all of your parameters would have the default value. But that's a very cumbersome solution, you should think about the state management and how to keep this data model outside your widgets, update the data here.